# Null exception thrown when running mule, when a devkit 3.0.0 method that takes a @InboundAttachments param

Tags: mule, devkit

I'm trying to make use of @attachment http properties

I have a devkit method called validate in a flow that is called like so

```
<http:connector name="httpConnector" doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS">
    <service-overrides
        messageFactory="org.mule.transport.http.HttpMultipartMuleMessageFactory" />
</http:connector>
<flow name="AttachmentTestFlow1" doc:name="AttachmentTestFlow1">        
    <http:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="httpConnector" doc:name="HTTP" exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8100"/>
    <Foo:validate config-ref="TestMessageSizeHappy"  />
</flow>
```

In Devkit:

```
@Processor
public Object validate(@Payload InputStream in
    ,@InboundAttachments("*") Map<String, DataHandler> inboundAttachments
    ,@OutboundAttachments Map<String, DataHandler> outboundAttachments
    ) {
```

however when running my mule application this is thrown:

> ERROR 2013-07-30 09:06:39,225 [main]
>   org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of
>   element 'xmlthreatprotection:validate' is not complete. One of
>   '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":annotations,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xmlthreatprotection":inbound-attachments}'
>   is expected.  at
>   org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown
>   Source)

It seems to me that mule expects the attachments to be put in as an attribute some how !
When I remove the @attachment stuff I get no errors at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this is supported by DevKit? I can not find a single integration test in the source code that exercises `@InboundAttachments` and `@OutboundAttachments` annotations, while `@InboundHeaders` and `@OutboundHeaders` are both test covered.

Alternatively you can receive the `MuleEvent` and access the attachments through it:

```
@Processor
@Inject
public Object validate(@Payload InputStream in, MuleEvent muleEvent) {
```

Comment: I've tried it in 3.0.0 and it throws an exception and 3.2. and 3.4 it doesn't even compile, we found that you could get multipart attachements only working with very specific inbound implementation details

Comment: So I don't think that its supported, its probably an extra annotation from my IDE. I might play with the @headers you mentioned!

Comment: Do you prefer the @InboundHeaders and OutboundHeaders or the MuleEvent?

Comment: its kind of funny how you have to add **muleEvent-ref="foo"** to your flow to get the MuleEvent to work, and devkit 3.4.0 to compile

Comment: I found it useful to use 
**<http:inbound-endpoint disableTransportTransformer="true"**  to get the full payload sent and not have the parts split up and sent to the flow seperatly

Comment: You do not need to add `muleEvent-ref` to your flow. Mule passes the `MuleEvent` to your method without it (if you have correctly add the `@Inject` annotation).